# ASP.Net page export to pdf

Tags: asp.net, export-to-pdf

I got stuck with my ASP.Net export to PDF. Below are my codes. Please help.

```
Response.Clear();    
Response.Buffer = true;    
Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName;    
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Response.Write(string.Format("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset={0}>", Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName));

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";    
Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=pdffilename.pdf");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
sb.Append("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");    
sb.Append("X-Document-Type: Worksheet\r\n");    
sb.Append("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"----=mtrSystem\"\r\n\r\n\r\n");    
sb.Append("------=mtrSystem\r\n");    
sb.Append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");    
sb.Append("<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\r\n");    
sb.Append("xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:pdf\">\r\n\r\n\r\n");     
sb.Append("------=mtrSystem\r\n");    
sb.Append("Content-ID: baiduimg\r\n");    
sb.Append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");    
sb.Append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n");
```

Can i use this way to export my ASP.Net page to PDF?

Comment: Maybe, but I'd use an HttpHandler instead and look into http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried? What steps have you taken to narrow down where the error is coming from? What errors are being thrown? What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 2):

Html-to-pdf.net allows for converting html to pdf.  TO get the html from an asp.net page, use the following code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Server.Execute("PageToConvert.aspx", sw);
string htmlCodeToConvert = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Then pass the html to the pdf generator:

```
public byte[] GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString (string htmlString)
```

You can then save the bytes to the response to send to client, or save on the server as a local file.

**EDIT:**

Something to keep in mind, html-to-pdf does [cost money](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Pricing.aspx), but for my last project it was a justified expense.  You can use the trial version to figure out what you needd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but generally I can highly recommend [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/) for creating PDF documents in code...